# Passing "-parameters" option in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, java-11

I'm trying to make a Java 11 Project run in Intellij. When executing tests some of them crash with following error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: For
>   queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method
>   parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+
>   use the javac flag -parameters.; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you
>   need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query
>   method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.

I added -parameters to JUnit default run configuration:
[image]

Which causes this error:

> Unrecognized option: -parameters
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Same error (add javac flag -parameters) occurs when I try to start application (i.e. run tomcat on which it's deployed). I tried to add this option to compiler option here:
[image]
But this seems to have no effect at all.

I'm confused: Where Am I supposed to add this argument to make tests and application run?

I'm using:

- Intellij Ultimate 2018.3
- JDK 11.0.1
- Maven 3.6.0
- AspectJ 1.9.2

Comment: Perhaps, you have to change “Ajc” to “javac”. And “target bytecode version 1.5” does not work with `-parameters`.

Comment: First module with target bytecode version is only parent module of a multi module project, it contains no source code at all. Up to now ajc compiler was needed to because we use aspectJ and some generated classes could not be found with javac compiler.

Comment: A module which contains no source code, doesn’t need the `-parameters` option. This option must be present when compiling the source code containing the parameter declarations to byte code.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried running project again and was not able to reproduce the errors I got again. I have no idea why they occured or why they disappeared.

Comment: Perhaps, you didn’t do a full rebuild when you added the compiler option but have (directly or indirectly) recompiled the sources now?

Comment: I used Intellij's "Build Project" option, I assume this does a full rebuild?